# what is the difference between opendialog and Tntopendialog (Delphi 7)

Tags: delphi

I have come across components TntOpenDialog , TntSaveDialog etc. What is the additional features provided by these components over standard Windows components? I could not find help about it , so any info is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: yes, they seemed same in functionality to me

Comment: IMO they are pretty old and should not be used anymore, because builtin components do everything we need...

Comment: @Marco : are u saying that these components predate the standard ones?

Comment: I used them a long long long time ago... and for a period (I don't know if it was solved now) they did not work on Vista.

Comment: What additional features are you looking for?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : Nothing actually, just researching through

Comment: @Marco, True, I've tried to set the filter `すべてのファイル (*.*)|*.*` and run my application on Japanese Windows Vista and it displays well known `?`s. So it seems there's still something wrong.

Comment: @TLama perhaps the font charset setting is wrong or the font simply doesn't support the characters? I've tested TNT some time ago on Japanese Vista too, and it seemed to work properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, they simply provide the same functionality as the standard OpenDialog, SaveDialog etc. but enabled for Unicode.

Comment: Cyprus: People using Delphi 2009, 2010, XE, or XE2, or later get unicode awareness in their standard OpenDialog etc. And if you were to go ahead and add the TnT stuff to your delphi 7 app, it will be just one more thing you have to undo when upgrading to a unicode delphi version.